# Different output for seemingly similar line of code. Why?

Tags: python, oop

In this program, I noticed that when I used print to display the intersection of two sets, there is difference in the output, one formats according to `__str__()` other just prints out the list. Why is it so ? Is it true for all the other python magic functions ?  Sorry for such a long code.

```
    class intSet(object):
            """An intSet is a set of integers
            The value is represented by a list of ints, self.vals.
            Each int in the set occurs in self.vals exactly once."""

            def __init__(self):
                """Create an empty set of integers"""
                self.vals = []

            def insert(self, e):
                """Assumes e is an integer and inserts e into self""" 
                if not e in self.vals:
                    self.vals.append(e)

            def member(self, e):
                """Assumes e is an integer
                   Returns True if e is in self, and False otherwise"""
                return e in self.vals

            def remove(self, e):
                """Assumes e is an integer and removes e from self
                   Raises ValueError if e is not in self"""
                try:
                    self.vals.remove(e)
                except:
                    raise ValueError(str(e) + ' not found')

            def intersect(self, other):
                """Input: two set of integers - sel and other
                   Returns intersection of the two sets.
                """
                temp = self.vals[:]
                for e in temp:
                    if e not in other.vals:
                        self.vals.remove(e)   
                return self.vals

           def __str__(self):
                """Returns a string representation of self"""
                self.vals.sort()
                return '{' + ','.join([str(e) for e in self.vals]) + '}'


    setA = intSet()
    setA.insert(3)
    setA.insert(4)
    setA.insert(5)

    setB = intSet()
    setB.insert(6)
    setB.insert(4)
    setB.insert(8)

    print("setA: ", setA)
    print("setB: ", setB)

    setA.intersect(setB)
    print(setA)             #output: {4}

    print("setA.intersect(setB): ", setA.intersect(setB))   #output: [4]
```

Comment: `print("setA: ", setA)` calls the `__str__` method since you're printing the  `intSet` object. When you call `.intersect`, you are not returning an `intSet` object, but rather a list. So you're not actually calling `intSet.__str__`, you're actually calling `list.__str__`.

Comment: I am returning "self.vals" to the function "intersect()". Is "self.vals" not a intSet object ? I am a little confused here.

Comment: No, `self.vals` is not an `intSet` object. Look where you define it under the `__init__`.  `self.vals = []` makes it so that `vals` is a `list`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the `print(setA)` prints the intSet object instance and the `print("setA.intersect(setB): ", setA.intersect(setB))` is printing the return value of the intersect method which is a list.

Comment: Thanks for the help.